# How to activate a specific card in Sencha Touch from a different Card using onclick

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I've got a few different cards in my app, and I'm trying to activate one of my sub cards from my homepage screen.

Here is the pertinent information.

**Setup**

```
Ext.setup({
    id: 'Ext-setup',
    onReady: function () {
        rpc.main.init();
    }
});
```

**Main**

```
rpc.main = {
    init: function () {
        var rootPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
            id: 'rpc-rootPanel',
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'card',
            region: 'center',
            items: [
                rpc.controllers.HomeController,
                rpc.controllers.VimeoController,
            ]
        });
    }
};
```

**HomeController**

```
rpc.controllers.HomeController = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'rpc-controllers-homecontroller',
    layout: 'card',
    items: [rpc.views.Home.index],
    listeners: {
        activate: function () {
            if (rpc.stores.HomeStore.getCount() === 0) {
                // This store uses the rpc.templates.AboutDetails XTemplate
                rpc.stores.HomeStore.load();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Home Index View**

```
rpc.views.Home.index = new Ext.DataView({
    id: 'rpc-views-home-index',
    itemSelector: 'div.home-index',
    tpl: rpc.templates.AboutDetails,
    store: rpc.stores.HomeStore,
    fullscreen: true,
});
```

**Vimeo Controller**

```
rpc.controllers.VimeoController = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'rpc-controllers-VimeoController',
    layout: 'card',
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [rpc.views.Vimeo.index,
            rpc.views.Vimeo.Details]
});
```

**Vimeo Index View**

```
rpc.views.Vimeo.index = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'rpc-views-Vimeo-index',
    layout: 'fit',
    dockedItems: [{xtype: 'toolbar', title: 'Videos'}]
    // stuff left out to keep it clean
});
```

**The Template I'm using to try and activate the card** *This is where you'll see the javascript call `javascript:goToCard();`*

```
rpc.templates.AboutDetails = new Ext.XTemplate(
'   <tpl for=".">',
'      <div class="padded">',
'          <div class="rounded-div">',
'              <h1>RockPointe Church</h1>',
'              <span class="rpc-sub">One church meeting in multiple locations.</span>',
'          </div>',
'      <div>',
'      <div id="quick-nav">',
'          <ul>',
'               <li><span onclick="javascript:goToCard(\'rpc-controllers-VimeoController\',\'rpc-views-Vimeo-index\');">Videos</span></li>',
'               <li><span onclick="javascript:goToCard()">Events</span></li>',
'               <li><span onclick="javascript:goToCard()">Sites</span></li>',
'          </ul>',
'          <br clear="left">',
'      </div>',
'   </tpl>'
```

**And finally, the `goToCard();` method**

```
function goToCard(panelId, cardId) {
    Ext.getCmp(panelId).setActiveItem(cardId);
}
```

The problem is simple... nothing happens when I click on the

```
<span onclick="javascript:goToCard(\'rpc-controllers-VimeoController\',\'rpc-views-Vimeo-index\');">Videos</span>
```

If I run the code directly in my console

```
Ext.getCmp('rpc-controllers-VimeoController').setActiveItem('rpc-views-Vimeo-index');
```

I get the following output.

> subclass
>   additionalCls: Array[0]
>   autoRender: true
>   body: El.Ext.Element.Ext.extend.constructor
>   cardSwitchAnimation: "slide"
>   componentCls: "x-panel"
>   componentLayout: subclass
>   container: El.Ext.Element.Ext.extend.constructor
>   dockedItems: Ext.util.MixedCollection
>   el: El.Ext.Element.Ext.extend.constructor
>   events: Object
>   fullscreen: true
>   getTargetEl: function () {
>   height: 306
>   hidden: true
>   hiddenOwnerCt: false
>   iconCls: "tv"
>   id: "rpc-controllers-VimeoController"
>   initialConfig: Object
>   items: Ext.util.MixedCollection
>   layout: subclass
>   layoutOnShow: Ext.util.MixedCollection
>   monitorOrientation: true
>   mons: Array[0]
>   needsLayout: false
>   originalGetTargetEl: function () {
>   ownerCt: subclass
>   renderData: Object
>   renderSelectors: Object
>   renderTo: null
>   rendered: true
>   scroll: "vertical"
>   scrollEl: El.Ext.Element.Ext.extend.constructor
>   scroller: Ext.util.Scroller.Ext.extend.constructor
>   tab: subclass
>   title: "Video"
>   width: 798
>   **proto**: F

But nothing actually happens :-(
Basically, I don't get an error, nor does the appropriate view load.

I also tried
`Ext.getCmp('rpc-controllers-VimeoController').layout.setActiveItem('rpc-views-Vimeo-index');`

But the response was even less...

> False

If I just run
`Ext.getCmp('rpc-controllers-VimeoController');`
I can see the `'rpc-views-Vimeo-index'` ID within the items array.

Comment: Why are you escaping the single quotes in the onclick handler?

Comment: because it's not in HTML, but rather in a javascript template.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Why don't you attach the event handler, instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: if you look at my edits, even calling the "supposedly" exact method directly in the console STILL doesn't load the view as required. If I can get the view to load like I want, I'll have no problem coding it however I need to to keep it DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your whole application structure is fairly bizarre. You're creating panels and calling them controllers for some reason and then nesting these panels.

All that aside-- the reason you're not seeing anything is because while you are setting the active item on the 'rpc-controllers-VimeoController' panel you never tell it to change the active item of the panel being displayed-- which from the looks of your nesting madness is 'rpc-rootPanel'. So you'd need to set the active item of 'rpc-rootPanel' to your 'rpc-controllers-VimeoController' and then set the active item of 'rpc-controllers-VimeoController' to rpc-views-Vimeo-index. /facepalm

Despite the bad design practices to answer your question you can most likely just do this:

```
 function goToCard(panelId, cardId) {
   Ext.getCmp('rpc-rootPanel').setActiveItem(1);
   Ext.getCmp(panelId).setActiveItem(cardId);
 }
```

You'll need to have some if-thens in there to check what panelId your link is for and set the root panel active item accordingly. The above is specific for your referenced link...

Comment: Thank you for the details. This is my first Sencha Touch app so I'm super new to it. I'm basically trying to lay it out the same as an ASP.NET MVC app, except I'm not entirely sure all the lingo. I'll refactor as needed once I learn some more. In the mean time, I'm going to test your solution.

Comment: your solution worked perfectly. Now to learn why a Panel isn't a Controller.

Comment: It's all good... starting out with sencha touch is pretty annoying--there is no consistency to the way they design applications from example to example even in their own examples directory.

Comment: Yup, that's been exactly my experience. What I'd love to see is the basics of MVC in an app without anything other than, 4 or 5 views, 2 controllers, and NO content. If I can see that, I might have a fighting chance.

Comment: I might be able to help you with that. Can I put email addresses in these comments without violating some TOS? who knows.. email me at christiantx (at) g m a i l.com and I'll see if I can't put something together real quick.